# Is there a way to write a file and append it to a zipped file in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to write a file and append it to a file that is already zipped. However, the same command works for unzipped files but when I use it for zipped files it overwrites the existing file in the drive, even when using `append = T`.

I am using `write.table()` for writing the file.

```
write.table(DT, file=gzfile("DT.DAT.gz"),
            sep=",",quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, 
            row.names = FALSE, na="", append = T)
```

The reason why I want this is because the existing file in the drive is extremely huge, and if I append them while unzipped it will take hours to zip manually. also reading the existing file in R and merge them then writing the zipped merged file is not optimal for me.

Comment: zip != gzip .....

Comment: … and in addition, gzip doesn’t support storing multiple files in a single archive, unlike zip. Instead, multiple gzipped files are usually bundled inside a tar archive. R does come with a `tar` utility function which might be useful for your purpose, but is usage is a bit finicky and I’ve found that it doesn’t always reliably find the `tar` binary, which limits its portability.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks for your input, I do not want to store multiple files. the gzipped file that I have in the drive contains only one file inside, I want to write a file that will be appended with the one that is already inside the gzipped file. Suppose I have file ```a.csv.gz``` in the drive which contains file ```a.csv``` inside, and I have DT ```b``` in R, I want to have ```a+b.csv.gz``` which contains rows of of DT ```b``` appended to file ```a.csv```

Comment: @Macosso I see. Unfortunately, doing that doesn’t seem possible with `gzfile` in R. However, you *can* concatenate gzipped files exactly the same as if they were text files. So what you can do is create multiple gz file outputs, and then concatenate these files (either using R, i.e. via `readBin` and `writeBin`, or just using your shell … e.g. `cat a.csv.gz b.csv.gz >a+b.csv.gz`).

Comment: (I just learned that concatenation of `.gz` files works ...) When you save the new data, you might prefer to omit column names (`header=FALSE`), relying on the existing file to have the headers for all data.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with the [tag:data.table] tag? Even if your data is a `data.table`-class object, you're using `write.table` which is base R, and behaves identically regardless if `data.frame` or `data.table`.

Comment: @revans because I am looking for a "data.table" solution.